# How should I pass multiple variables to url in jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am tryin to pass multiple values in the below method but I am unable to get this to work. What is the correct syntax?
I have tried

```
data: ('keyword='+$(this).val(),'id='10),
```

and

```
data: {'keyword='+$(this).val(),'id='10},
```

and

```
data: {'keyword='+$(this).val(),'&id='10}//I have also tried to replace the curly braces with brackets.
```

This works so I think its a syntax problem?

```
data: ('keyword='+$(this).val())
```

Here is my complete request. I am using GET, I have tried using POST to no avail.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "showhints.php",
    data: ('keyword='+$(this).val()),
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(loading.gif) no-repeat 165px");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#suggesstion-box").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest is to use an object literal which will then be uri encoded internally

```
data: {keyword: $(this).val(), id : 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like

```
...
data: {
            keyword: $(this).val(),
            id: 10
},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple values like this

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "showhints.php",
            data: {'key':'value','key':'value',..},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(loading.gif) no-repeat 165px");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="surname">
    <input type="submit" name="submitForm">
</form>
```

Ajax call:

```
var name = $('input[name]');
var surname = $('input[surname]');
$('input[submitForm]').click(function() {
    url: 'someLink.php',
    dataType: json,
    data: {
        name: name.val(),
        surname: surname.val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```